# Remapping Alt+Key to same Key not working?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, logitech-keyboard

Here is my current keyboard, a Logitech K270:

[image: Logitech K270 Keyboard]

I want to override the <kbd>Browser_Home</kbd> like this:

1. <kbd>Browser_Home</kbd> >>> <kbd>Media_Next</kbd>
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Browser_Home</kbd> >>> <kbd>Browser_Home</kbd>

While the first remap works the second does not, and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Browser_Home</kbd> results in <kbd>Media_Next</kbd> being sent. Here is the relevant portion of my script:

```
Browser_Home::Send {Media_Next}
!Browser_Home::Send {Browser_Home} ; this one is ignored
```

---

I don't know if this is due to Logitech, AHK's implementation, or a logical error in my AHK script (likely).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a combined hotkey approach?

```
; $ = Force keyboard hook such that Send command won't trigger itself
; * = Prefix to allow firing with any other hotkey combination as long as that key is pressed

$*Browser_Home::
    If GetKeyState("Alt", "P")  ; See if user is holding the Alt key down
        Send {Browser_Home}
    Else
        Send {Media_Next}
Return
```

Or combined using the ternary operator:

```
$Browser_Home::Send, % GetKeyState("Alt", "P") ? "{Browser_Home}" : "{Media_Next}"
```

I don't know if this actually works or not (i.e., not tested), just something to try.

Sometimes it's easier to debug where things are going wrong when you have a combined hotkey by adding `MsgBox` statements in on the various test cases to see which ones are executing or not, and then if they appear to execute (for a particular send statement for example), then you can go look in the keystroke log via the tray icon and see what actually got sent, or possibly ignored/blocked due to the hotkey syntax or whatnot (if it's set up inadvertently in a way where AutoHotkey is blocking what you would like it to send)

Answer (score 0):

```
*Browser_Home::
GetKeyState, OutputVar, alt , P
if(OutputVar = "D")
{
    ;~ MsgBox,  alt down %OutputVar%
    Send {Browser_Home}
    sleep, 250
}
else if(OutputVar = "U")
{
    Send {Media_Next}  
    sleep, 250
}
return
*Browser_Home up::
sleep, 50
return
```

I hope this help (times up to you)
or

```
Browser_Home::Send, {Media_Next}
Alt & Browser_Home::send, {Browser_Home}
```